как отобрать пользователей в sql которые присоединились после 1 января 2016 года
Я писала ответ на задачу так :
SELECT u.id, u.first_name,u.last_name FROM users AS u,users_p AS up WHERE up.series='32%' AND u.date_joined (а дальше - не понимаю, как сформулировать запрос)
Как написать, что мне нужны только пользователи, которые зарегистрировались после полуночи 1 января 2016 года 

SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name  FROM users AS u, users_p AS up  WHERE up.series LIKE '32%'  AND u.date_joined > '2016-01-01 00:00:00';

cпасибо, получилось!

На будущее: как я знаю такие вопросы нельзя тут задавать, вы должны сами подумать и попытаться найти ответ, я более чем уверен что подобных вопросов не мало.
